# Cannot properly type function returns functions

Tags: typescript

I am a beginner when it comes to TypeScript. I have a function that returns an object containing of two functions, simple as that. I've defined a return interface for it, but for some reason, when I try to use one of the returned, I am getting

> TS2339: Property 'get' does not exist on type '() => { get: (url:
>   string) => string | null; set: ({ url, body }: SetItemInterface) =>
>   void; }'.

Here's the code:

```
import * as Express from "express";

interface StorageInterface {
  [url: string]: {
    body: string;
    date: number;
  };
}

interface SetItemInterface {
  body: string;
  url: string;
}

interface ItemInterface {
  body: string;
  date: number;
}

interface CacheFunctionInterface {
  get(url: string): string | null;
  set(params: SetItemInterface): void;
}

const cache = (): CacheFunctionInterface => {
  const storage: StorageInterface = {};
  const cacheTime: number = 1000;

  /**
   * Creates or updates item in store.
   * @param {string} url
   * @param {string} body
   */
  const setItem = ({ url, body }: SetItemInterface): void => {
    storage.url = {
      body,
      date: Number(+new Date()) + cacheTime,
    };
  };

  /**
   * Gets the item if exists, otherwise null;
   * @param {string} url
   */
  const getItem = (url: string): string | null => {
    const item: ItemInterface = storage[url];
    const currentTime = +new Date();

    if (!!item) {
      if (item.date > currentTime) {
        return item.body;
      }
    }

    return null;
  };

  return {
    get: getItem,
    set: setItem,
  };
};

const cacheMiddleware = (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response, next: Express.NextFunction) => {
  const { url }: { url: string } = req;
  const item: string | null = cache.get(url); // Here's the problem

  if (!!item) {
    return res.send(item);
  }

  return next();
};

export { cacheMiddleware };
export default cache;
```

and [the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=import%20*%20as%20Express%20from%20%22express%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20StorageInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Burl%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20body%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SetItemInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20body%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20url%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ItemInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20body%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20date%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20CacheFunctionInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20get(url%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20set(params%3A%20SetItemInterface)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20cache%20%3D%20()%3A%20CacheFunctionInterface%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20storage%3A%20StorageInterface%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20cacheTime%3A%20number%20%3D%201000%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F**%0D%0A%20%20%20*%20Creates%20or%20updates%20item%20in%20store.%0D%0A%20%20%20*%20%40param%20%7Bstring%7D%20url%0D%0A%20%20%20*%20%40param%20%7Bstring%7D%20body%0D%0A%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20const%20setItem%20%3D%20(%7B%20url%2C%20body%20%7D%3A%20SetItemInterface)%3A%20void%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20storage.url%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20body%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20date%3A%20Number(%2Bnew%20Date())%20%2B%20cacheTime%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F**%0D%0A%20%20%20*%20Gets%20the%20item%20if%20exists%2C%20otherwise%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20*%20%40param%20%7Bstring%7D%20url%0D%0A%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20const%20getItem%20%3D%20(url%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20item%3A%20ItemInterface%20%3D%20storage%5Burl%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20currentTime%20%3D%20%2Bnew%20Date()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!!item)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(item.date%20%3E%20currentTime)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20item.body%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%3A%20getItem%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set%3A%20setItem%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20cacheMiddleware%20%3D%20(req%3A%20Express.Request%2C%20res%3A%20Express.Response%2C%20next%3A%20Express.NextFunction)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20%7B%20url%20%7D%3A%20%7B%20url%3A%20string%20%7D%20%3D%20req%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20item%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%20%3D%20cache.get(url)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20if%20(!!item)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20res.send(item)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20next()%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20%7B%20cacheMiddleware%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aexport%20default%20cache%3B%0D%0A).

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cache` is a function:

```
const cache = (): CacheFunctionInterface => { ...
```

and you treat it as an object by trying to call `.get` method on it.

```
cache.get(...
```

Comment: Oh gosh, you're totally right! This is so simple! Thanks a lot!

Comment: i'd make more helpful/detailed answer, but your code is not focused enough (large amount of code, not sure what is your intention), so it's hard to do so.

Comment: No, no, no, your answer is perfect. I simply forgot that the `cache` is a function and I expected it to be an object. Invoking it was all it took to make it all work.